# Getting appointments for the next 5 days using php

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to write a script to pull dates for the next 7 days and put them into a div for each date :

```
    echo '<div class="dateboxcontainer">';
    for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++){
        echo '<div class="datebox"><div class="topdate">'.strtoupper(date("D d", mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, date("d")+$i, 0))."\n").
        '</div><div class="bottomdate">An appointment for the day</div></div>';
    }  
    echo '</div>';
```

[image]

Im now trying to pull data from my database from two fields 'datedroppingoff' and 'datepickingup', which are formatted like this '2013-07-10 14:29:28'.

Im kind of stuck though as im not sure what query to write to put the appointments for each day into each day div where 'some info' currently sits.

Im guessing it would be something like

```
Select * FROM jobdetails WHERE datedroppingoff OR datepickingup = WHATEVER DAY IS BEING ECHO'D OUT
```

but im not quite sure how I can compare the date stored in jobdetails for that row to the date being echo'd out ?.

Edit>>>>>

Thanks for the answers below, iv managed to come up with the following, it echos out the date boxes ok, but doesnt bring in any data, so im not sure if I have the sql part correct ?.

```
            echo '<div class="dateboxcontainer">';
     $eventdata = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM `jobdetails`
    SQL;
    if(!$events = $db->query($eventdata)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    // read first event
    if ($nextEvent = mysql_fetch_assoc($events)) { // here is the first one
        extract($nextEvent); // prepare its variables
        // use the event date it to control the inner loop
        $nextDate = $datedroppingoff;
    } else // no events?
        $nextDate = 0; // prepare a fake date value

    // calculate today date
    $currentDate = mktime();

    // loop on the dates for the next 7 days
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 7; $i++) {

        $currentEvents = "";

        // loop to print every event for current day (first one already extracted)
        while ($nextDate == date("Y-m-d", $currentDate)) { // next event occurs today

            // here prepare the var containing the event description
            // BTW, I'd use a list for the events
            $currentEvents .= "· $name<br>"; // use every field you need from current DB row

            // read next event
            if ($nextEvent = mysql_fetch_assoc($events)) { // here is the next one
                extract($nextEvent); // prepare its variables
                // use the event date it to control the inner loop
                $nextDate = $datedroppingoff;
            } else // no more events?
                $nextDate = 0; // prepare a fake date value
        }

        echo "
            <div class='datebox'>
                <div class='topdate'>" . strtoupper(date("D d m Y", $currentDate)) . "</div>
                <div class='bottomdate'>$currentEvents</div>
            </div>";

        $currentDate = strtotime("+1 day", $currentDate);
    } 
    echo '</div>';
```

Comment: `WHERE (date(datedroppingoff) >= 'startdate' AND date(datedroppingoff) <= 'enddate') OR (date(datepickingup) >= 'startdate' AND date(datepickingup) <= 'enddate')`.. For easy formatting, look at the `DateTime` and possibly `DateInterval` objects.

Comment: How do I add this into the for loop for the next 7 days though, thats what im having trouble with ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this in the end which seems to do the job ! :)

```
    // Date box container
    echo '<div class="dateboxcontainer">';
    // Loop through and create a date for the next 7 days
    $days = new DatePeriod(new DateTime, new DateInterval('P1D'), 7); 
    foreach ($days as $day) {
    echo '<div class="datebox">';
    echo '<div class="topdate">';

          echo strtoupper($day->format('D d')) . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</div>';


              // Get the names for each day
          $theday = strtoupper($day->format('Y-m-d'));    
          $sqldate = <<<SQL
        SELECT *
        FROM `jobdetails`
        WHERE datedroppingoff = '$theday' OR datepickingup = '$theday'
    SQL;
    if(!$resultdate = $db->query($sqldate)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    while($rowdate = $resultdate->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $rowdate['name'];
            }
         //

    echo '</div>';
    }  
    echo '</div>';
    //
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobdetails` WHERE (`datedroppingoff ` > '2013-07-01 00:00:00' AND `datedroppingoff `  '2013-07-02 00:00:00') OR  (`datepickingup ` > '2013-07-01 00:00:00' AND `datepickingup `  '2013-07-02 00:00:00');
```

This will have to be repeated per day (i.e. for each of the 5 days)

To do a nice loop, use an array populated with the next 5 dates as strings. Then do a foreach over the dates and run this query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all dates from now and for the next 5 days, you could use:

```
WHERE
    `datedroppingoff` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) OR
    `datepickingup ` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: How do I wrap that into the for loop so that that it appears within the day divs ?

Comment: probably best to do it this way (not a looped query, but before you start the loop) and then handle the data from the result set, rather than running a query on every day iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how I'd proceed (by the way, this is my first answer, so I'm a little excited...)

First, some basic assumptions for this ultra-fast script (sorry, not so much time now to test it thoroughly).

- your Appointment table has a field with the date of the appointment
- your result resource ($events) contains only the rows for the current week
- the resulting rows are sorted by the date field, ascending (from oldest to newest)

Try this (I've changed a bit your original code, sorry)

```
// read first event
if ($nextEvent = mysql_fetch_assoc($events)) { // here is the first one
    extract($nextEvent); // prepare its variables
    // use the event date it to control the inner loop
    $nextDate = $DB_field_with_event_date;
} else // no events?
    $nextDate = 0; // prepare a fake date value

// calculate today date
$currentDate = mktime();

// loop on the dates for the next 7 days
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 7; $i++) {

    $currentEvents = "";

    // loop to print every event for current day (first one already extracted)
    while ($nextDate == date("Y-m-d", $currentDate)) { // next event occurs today

        // here prepare the var containing the event description
        // BTW, I'd use a list for the events
        $currentEvents .= "· $your_desc_field<br>"; // use every field you need from current DB row

        // read next event
        if ($nextEvent = mysql_fetch_assoc($events)) { // here is the next one
            extract($nextEvent); // prepare its variables
            // use the event date it to control the inner loop
            $nextDate = $DB_field_with_event_date;
        } else // no more events?
            $nextDate = 0; // prepare a fake date value
    }

    echo "
        <div class='datebox'>
            <div class='topdate'>" . strtoupper(date("D d m Y", $currentDate)) . "</div>
            <div class='bottomdate'>$currentEvents</div>
        </div>";

    $currentDate = strtotime("+1 day", $currentDate);
}
```

Tried a couple of times on fake data and it should work. IMHO better to directly alias the date field to get the nextDate var directly from the DB, so avoiding the rows,

```
            $nextDate = $DB_field_with_event_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, im just going to edit my question and add the sql database lookup as I think im making a mess of it ! :-S

Comment: There are a problem in your script: you're getting all the appointments and not those of this week only (second assumption). You should use one of the other answers. Anyway, if you could add a table dump of "jobdetails" I think I could write also the DB lookup part to integrate here.

Comment: I always hesitate to insert a db query in a loop, I find it time-consuming and system-overheading (you're calling the SQL server 7 times, terrible if you have let's say 3 months to show). Usually I prefer get the right results and then traverse them.